# Refactoring if/else statement for time span between two years

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement, merge

I'm currently programming an web-app. Users are able to input two years of a period of time, something like 2005 and 2014 and then the app shows all activity only between these two years, so more specifically the user sees all activity of 2005, 2006, 2007, ... 2014.

To make this dynamic and simpler, I just made activity lists of every year (json2005, json2006, ...) and not of every time spans (json2005-2006, json2005-2007) and then found a way to merge all lists between the years the user picked together to a big list of that timespan. The code looks like this:

```
if (year1 == year2) {
    json = window["json" + year1];
}
else {
    if (year2 == (year1 + 1)) {
        json = $.extend(window["json" + year1], window["json" + (year1+1)]);
    }
    else {
        if (year2 == (year1 + 2)) {
            json = $.extend(window["json" + year1], window["json" + (year1+1)], window["json" + (year1+2)]);
        }
        else {
            if (year2 == (year1 + 3)) {
                json = $.extend(window["json" + year1], window["json" + (year1+1)], window["json" + (year1+2)], window["json" + (year1+3)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(The `window[]` is a way to make variables dynamic, if you wonder what that means.)

Code explained:

If year1 is equal to year2, everything is clear, we just take the list of year1 (we could also use year2, because its the same) because we just have one year.

If year2 comes directly after year1 (year2 = year1 + 1), there are no years between them, so we only need two lists, the one of the first year and the one of the second year, basically we merge year1 with year2 and boom, we have a big list with everything from year1 to year2.

If year2 is further away, it all gets a bit ugly. In the code you see, if year2 is year1 + 3, we have to merge together 4(!) different lists and have to write every list down. So we have to write:

```
json = $.extend(window["json" + year1], window["json" + (year1+1)], window["json" + (year1+2)], window["json" + (year1+3)]);
```

Buuut, my web app has 25 years to handle, from 1995 to 2020, that makes 325 different merge lines.

My question is: is there a way to make this much much shorter than it is now?

Because I think there is a way, I just don't have enough JavaScript experience and methods knowledge to find it out by myself. I mean, the problem is pretty simple, we just need somehow an index or a way to know the difference between two years to declare how many years we have to merge but here I gave up.

Also I had the idea to use factorization, but that's too complicated for my head. But maybe factorization is the keyword, the cue for the solution. I really don't know. Maybe it also could help, if I could write if/else statements into an `$.extend()`; function (can I?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
json = data["json" + year1];
var this_year = year1 + 1;
while(this_year <= year2) {
   json = $.extend(json, data["json" + this_year]);
   this_year = this_year + 1;
}
```

Instead of trying to extend everything in one go, it will progressively extend with each year's data. Just be aware that `$.extend` will replace the value of common keys with the latest one. If you need to merge the values that gets a little harder (but is doable - we would just need an example).

Comment: I have actually wrote that code

`(function($){$.concat||$.extend({concat:function(b,c){var a=[];for(var x in arguments)if(typeof a=='object')a=a.concat(arguments[x]);return a}});})(jQuery);`

and changed the extends to concats, but wanted to make my question simpler,

you can see the original code here:
http://s448350928.online.de/pumpn/mag/collabplan/collabplan.js

just to make clear, the merging works with this workaround code

Comment: That's a bit beyond me! I'll trust it works and can be adapted. FYI I've fixed a couple of typos in my code and it should work now.

Comment: okay, thanks...i tried out your code and my app crashes immediately if i input a year...i don't even know what the while method is, haha :D

i don't even get errors, the complete site crashes :/

Comment: On second thought - can you try renaming `window` to something else? `window` means something specific in browser-based JavaScript - it means the browser window!

Comment: hmmm, i really don't know how to rename that and to what... :(

Comment: i replaced it with "data" and get the error "data is not defined"

Comment: omg
so i don't know why, but my year1 and my year2 were strings and not numbers...at least after i input the years
sorry for that, i hope i can fix it now and will accept your answer as soon everything works :)

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU @OWEN

Comment: Will he get a cookie?

Comment: @Zenadix to cite my changelog: "owen kriegt ein cookie und everything :*" :D